# Что такое отказоустойчивость?

Tags: терминология

На работе дали задачу:

> сделать отказоустойчивую программу для АЭС.

Так вот, что включает в себя термин "отказоустойчивость"?

Если я сделаю много try/catch без обработки исключений и отключу проверку на переполнение, то будет ли считаться моя программа отказоустойчивой, ведь она никогда не упадет?

Comment: Особенно важно отключить проверку на переполнение! Ну и что, что такая полностью отказоустойчивая программа когда-то из-за переполнения [носитель "Ариан" грохнула](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F_%C2%AB%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD-5%C2%BB_%284_%D0%B8%D1%8E%D0%BD%D1%8F_1996_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%29)? :) Видите ли, отказоустойчивость не может быть важнее правильности...

Comment: И исключения надо бы обрабатывать. Отключите вы проверку деления на 0, в переменной останется не деленное значение, управляющие стержни вместо того, что бы подняться на величину N поднимутся на M*N ... Надеюсь ваша АЭС далеко от Москвы, мне переезжать еще не надо ? Так что все исключения надо явно обработать и для каждого случая продумать почему такое исключение может возникнуть и как его парировать, а если не знаете почему оно происходит сразу сбрасывайте аварийную защиту

Comment: Наверно, это означает, что программа будет не просто продолжать работать, но и работать правильно при любых нештатных ситуациях насколько это возможно... чтоб не как со стержнями из комментария выше

Comment: @Mike, я окончил ПТУ с отличием, а потом меня взяли в контору по блату, которая является мировым поставщиком ПО для АЭС.

Comment: мировым ... блин ... пора на Марс перебираться, хотя вы же туда то же силовые установки будете поставлять ... :) В общем все очень просто, поселитесь рядом с АЭС на которой будет стоять ваш софт и пишите так, что бы могли спать спокойно :)

Comment: [Отказоустойчивость](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: Скорее всего вам надо разработать программу, которая помимо тщательного анализа корректности всех входных данных является распределенной (желательно ее выполнять на территориально разнесенных 2-х (а лучше 3-х) компьютерах (иногда такой комплекс называют метрокластер)) и сравнивает результаты вычислений на разных узлах. Скорее всего, в дополнение к этому предстоит продумать систему создания контрольных точек и восстановления с них при повторном вводе в эксплуатацию отказавшего оборудования.